# Customize the camera roll and show the icon on iCloud media

Tags: swift, icloud, phasset, phassetcollection

Is there any way to check the media is physically available on device. In other words how to identify the iCloud media using swift or objective c.

I have tried to access below property but seems there is some issue with that.

```
public struct PHAssetSourceType : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)


    public static var typeUserLibrary: PHAssetSourceType { get }

    public static var typeCloudShared: PHAssetSourceType { get }

    public static var typeiTunesSynced: PHAssetSourceType { get }
}
```

Code to check iCloud media.

```
 let assetType = (self.assets?[indexPath.row])! as PHAsset
            // let sourceType = assetType.sourceType as PHAssetSourceType



if assetType.sourceType.rawValue == 2 /*.typeCloudShared*/ {
                (cell as! FNSCameraRollCollectionViewCell).iCloudImage.isHidden = false
            }

**OR** 

if assetType.sourceType == .typeCloudShared {
                (cell as! FNSCameraRollCollectionViewCell).iCloudImage.isHidden = false
            }
```

I am getting below result :

**PHAssetSourceType(rawValue: 1)**

My objective is to customize the camera roll and show the icon on iCloud media.

Comment: *I have tried to access below property*, *I am getting below result :* Please show the code

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad : I have update the code in the question it-self. Please check.